# Сортировка объектов в ArrayList

Tags: java

Как я могу отсортировать ArrayList объектов по конкретному общему double параметру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
youArrayList.sort((o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o2.getDoubleField(), o1.getDoubleField()));
```